# Do math using Django template filter?

Tags: python, django, templates, filter

In my database I have an integer field storing price information, like "10399", "84700".
When display, they should be "$103.99" and "$847.00".

I need int*0.01 to be displayed.

I was wondering if there is a way to do it using Django template filter? Like:

```
{{ item.price|int_to_float_and_times_0.01 }}
```

Another question, actually I chose integer because I thought it would be more efficient than using float in database. Is that true?

Comment: Integer is almost always considered the best way to represent money for storage purposes.

Answer (score 8):

You could make your own template filter which essentially does what you need by just dividing the input by 100.  For example:

in my_app/templatetags/currency_helper.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def to_currency(value):
    return float(value) / 100.0
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load currency_helper %}

etc...

{{item.price|to_currency}}
```

Also, if I were you, I would store currency values in your database as a decimal field to avoid the headache of doing this or dealing with roundoff error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`widthratio` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#widthratio) for division:

```
${% widthratio item.price 100 1 %}
```

(The result is (a/b)*c if a,b,c are the 3 parameters for `widthratio`)

will result in: `$103.99` (for 10399)

Comment: `widthratio` returns a whole number `{% widthratio 10399 100 1 %}` gives `104`, not `103.99`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify the integers before passing them to the template context, for example with a list comprehension:

```
context['prices'] = [float(item) * 0.01 for item in Model.objects.all()]
```

(You can also make it a generator by removing the brackets if you Python version supports it, it will make your code use less memory.)

It seems very unlikely that using `int` instead of `float` will make you website noticeably faster.
If you want a safe type for prices, use `decimal`: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can return a float, but you can format the number as a string:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def int_to_float_and_times(value):
  value = float(value) * .01
  return u'${0:.2f}'.format(value)

register.filter('int_to_float_and_times', int_to_float_and_times)
```

How do you define efficient? Usually monetary values are stored in special formats that try to do exact calculations.

edit: 0.01 is not allowed in a function name