# Convert negative number to positive number in django template?

Tags: python, django

How to convert negative number to positive number in django template?

```
{% for balance in balances %}
    {{ balance.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

If balance.amount is negative number, I want to convert it to positive number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588160/multiply-in-django-template

Comment: Can I doing that without create custom template tags?

Comment: Your question asks specifically about templates. Is there a reason why you don't want to do this in the view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would like to suggest installing [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters/0.1.2).

Then you can simply use the `abs` filter like this:

```
{% for balance in balances %}
    {{ balance.amount|abs }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want/can't install django-mathfilters

You can make a custom filter quite easily:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='abs')
def abs_filter(value):
    return abs(value)
```

Answer (score 7):

This works without adding django-mathfilters but it's not a very good practice.

```
{% if balance.amount < 0 %}
{% widthratio balance.amount 1 -1 %}
{% else %}
{{ balance.amount }}
{% endif %}
```

[Widthratio](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio) is meant for creating bar charts but can be used for [multiplication](http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/)

Comment: Oh man! `widthratio` to multiply! Hehe, way to think out of the box -- I love it the strangest of ways. Time for a public service announcement. If you ever do decide to use the above, please please please add `{# widthratio is being used to multiply balance.amount times -1 #}` to make this code have a smidgen of meaning.

Comment: Great Work Bro Keep it up

Answer (score 4):

from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771973/multiply-by-1-in-a-django-template):

```
{% if qty > 0 %}
  Please, sell {{ qty }} products.
{% elif qty < 0 %}
  Please, buy {{ qty|slice:"1:" }} products.
{% endif %}
```